# How to create a function in Ruby that take a average of an array?

Tags: ruby

I tried something like this:

```
def average_array_float(&array)
  array.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / array.size
end
```

no success

```
array = [1, 2, 3]

def even_numbers(array)
  array.select { |num| num.even? }
end

p array.even_numbers
```

reply:

```
$ bundle exec ruby main.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
main.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `even_numbers' called for [1, 2, 3]:Array (NoMethodError)
exit status 1
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello! Questions on Stackoverflow are intended to be in **English**. Please traduce it.

Comment: Ok! I forgot. Translated

Comment: i think you should include the complete code including the class if it exist and the even_numbers method

Answer (score 1):

You have to *pass* the array to the method:

```
def even_numbers(array)
  array.select { |num| num.even? }
end

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
even_numbers(array)
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

The `NoMethodError` in your example happens because if you define a method on the top-level, it becomes a *private* method of `Object`:

```
Object.private_methods
#=> [:initialize, :inherited, :method_added, :method_removed, :method_undefined,
#    :remove_const, :initialize_copy, :initialize_clone, :using, :public,
#    :ruby2_keywords, :protected, :private, :included, :extended, :prepended,
#    :even_numbers, :sprintf, :format, ...]
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And since `array` is an `Object`, it can access that method (privately).

If you really wanted to add the method to `Array`, you *could* open the corresponding class:

```
class Array
  def even_numbers
    select { |num| num.even? }
  end
end
```

Which gives you:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].even_numbers
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

However, although this works, it's not advised to alter objects that are not your own, let alone Ruby's core classes.

---

Regarding your other method, you could use [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#sum-method) and [`fdiv`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Integer.html#fdiv-method):

```
def average(array)
  array.sum.fdiv(array.size)
end

average([1, 2, 4])
#=> 2.3333333333333335
```

Or [`quo`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Numeric.html#quo-method) if you prefer a precise result:

```
def average(array)
  array.sum.quo(array.size)
end

average([1, 2, 4])
#=> (7/3)
```